# Exception in thread main error in array program

Tags: java, exception, program-entry-point

```
// getting exception in thread main error in  result[row][col]= arrayfirst [row][col] + arraysecound [row[col];

public class apples
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

     int arrayfirst[] [] ={{1,2,3},{2,3,4}};
     int arraysecound[] [] ={{3,4,5},{6,7,8}};
     int result[][]= new int [2][2];

      for(int row =0; row<arrayfirst.length; row++)
      {

          for(int col =0; col<arrayfirst[row].length; col++)
          { 

          result[row][col]= arrayfirst [row][col] + arraysecound [row][col];
          }
      }



      for(int row =0; row<arrayfirst.length; row++) {
            for(int col =0; col<arrayfirst[row].length; col++) { 
                System.out.print(" "+result[row][col]);
            } 
            System.out.println();
      }
}
}

// BUT THESE SIMILAR PROGRAMS RUNS CORRECTLY WHY

public static void main(String args[])
{

    int arrayA[][] = {{1,4,3,5},{3,8,1,2},{4,3,0,2},{0,1,2,7}};
    int arrayB[][] = {{6,1,0,8},{3,2,1,9},{5,4,2,9},{6,5,2,0}};
    int arrayC[][] = new int[4][4];

    for(int i = 0; i < arrayA.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j< arrayA[0].length; j++) {
            arrayC[i][j] = arrayA[i][j] + arrayB[i][j];

        //  System.out.print(arrayC[i][j] + "   ");

        } // end j for loop
    } // end i for loop

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayC.length; i++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < arrayC[i].length; x++) {
                System.out.print(arrayC[i][x] + "  | ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
} // end main
} // end class
```

Comment: Take a closer look at size of your `result` array

Comment: In the first example `arrayFirst` is a `2 x 3` matrix but `result` is `2 x 2`, and hence failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

int arrayfirst[] [] ={{1,2,3},{2,3,4}};
     int arraysecound[] [] ={{3,4,5},{6,7,8}};

here, arrayfirst and arraysecound contain two rows and three columns each ***(The number of inner curly braces separated by Comma signify number of rows, and the numbers written within these inner curly braces signify number of columns),*** so when you add their elements and try to store the result, you again need an array that has two rows and three columns.

so, just replace

int result[][]= new int [2][2];
with 
**int result[][]= new int [2][3];**

Answer (score 0):

Your result array in the first program is too small.

Answer (score 0):

Change following

```
int result[][]= new int [2][2];
```

to

```
int result[][]= new int [2][3];
```

Also, to learn more about arrays in java, have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: @user3371292 If the given answer resolved your issue, then please mark it as accepted solution